# Why Label column is needed in ML.net?

Tags: c#, machine-learning, ml.net

I have 20 million records of Dataset to train the model.

Why Label column I have to add?

Comment: i don't know ML.NET at all but without seeing any code and by thinking i would say how can you refer to that data later on if you do not assign a name to the column?

Comment: Sample code you can check from the official site of ml.net 
As I'm also started but not getting why we need additional ”Label” column to train the model.

Comment: Where as https://www.h2o.ai they don't need any additional column for the dataset.

Answer (score 5):

`Label` is how ML.NET calls the 'target variable', the one that you want to predict, based on the other variables, called features.

If you do not give ML.NET a 'label column name' (or a name of your 'target variable' column), it will assume that the label column is called `Label`. Hence the error you are probably seeing `Label column 'Label' is not found`.

Answer (score 3):

The "label" is what your model needs to predict. That is done by training your model with "features" or in other words, information that has relevance to the "label".

Answer (score 1):

For example lets say we have an image data in the form of pixels in an excel file, if you have a number "5" and it has 50 features.
Now 5 is what the "**label**" holds, and the 50 features are used to learn what a 5 looks like. 
So label is needed because otherwise it doesn't know what the features belong to.